# Type or NameSpace "Utilities" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net

I have got error. Please help me out.

> The type or namespace name 'Utilities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have made a class with the namespace Utililties.

```
namespace Utilities
{
    public class DatabaseManager
    {
        public string commandText;
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcTransaction _tran = null;

        public DatabaseManager(String dbConn) {
            OdbcConnection  _conn = new OdbcConnection(dbConn);
            cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
            _conn.Open();
        }

        public void setParameter(string name, OdbcType type, object value)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(name, type).Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The class works fine but I also have the same problem when using in from another project. I wonder what's happening and how to fix the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using Utilities;     // This line have error highlighted in red color
```

Comment: Could we see default.aspx & default.aspx.cs ?

Comment: have you referenced the project/dll?

Comment: Where is your DatabaseManager class? I'd expect a namespace of `Utilities` to contain code in a separate assembly - is that the case? If so, do you have a reference to that assembly?

Comment: To: Andras Zoltan. I do not compile the DatabaseManager class in dll. I just put it in the folder Utilities.

Comment: To Jon Skeet: I have reference to another source.dll. I do not know the source.dll have the namespace Utilities or not. Because the dll is not written by me. Will it cause the problem if this is happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [using namespace directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to import the types in name space, The other project (website) where you are accessing class would have different namespace. Make sure that you import by [adding reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the dll which has Utilities namespace. The statement given below will import types in Utilities, if containing assembly is available.

```
using Utilities;
```

**Edit:** If you have types in the namespace Utilities within website then you try putting them in app_code folder and build the website before you access them.

Comment: I have type the using Utilities. But the program pop up an error that "type or namespace do not exist".

Comment: Do you have the classes folder within web site?, try putting the class files in app_code and build the web site.

Comment: Thank you so much Adil. Putting in app_code solve the problem. May I ask why I need to put inside the AppCode. Because in other project. I do not have to do this action. I could still use the function in the class.

Comment: You are welcome, you may read this to understand app_code, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx